# Name and Template changes not being published

Tags: publishing

We have recently moved to Sitecore 8.2 Update 3 and facing following issue.

Whenever we are trying to change the template for any item, it does not seems to get published. And it empty the existing fields even though we have the same field names in the new template.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 2):

This is known publishing issue in Sitecore 8.2 Update 3.

Try to resolve the issue with this hotfix.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/136794